# Correct way to create foreground view on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to implement the next logic in Android:

[image]

We have RecyclerView with hours of days (8.00-17.00, after 17.00 we see 8.00 of the next day, so the list is infinite) and should add events according to their time. I implemented it using LinearLayoutManager and view holder is a day where I add events to absolute position of view). But I don't like this way, because every item view is a bit havy and list doesn't scroll smoothly when draws new item. Please help me find correct way to implement it.

Comment: If I had to implement this, I would make a custom `View` and use canvas draw* methods to render the UI.  It's more code and you have to do your own touch handling, but solves a lot of issues as well, such as scrolling performance.  It's an option worth considering.

Comment: You could consider looking for a library that fulfills your needs (or look through their code to see how they did it and adapt it). Came across a library that has screenshots that look similar to your provided image. https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Answer (score 0):

If the scrolling is not smooth then probably your `onBindViewHolder` is too heavy. There is no generic advice in this situation. You need to run `Android Studio->Android Monitor->CPU->Start Method Tracing` and analyse what actually slows down creating day view. Then optimise that part.

Also carefully check if you are not running any disk or database access code in UI thread. Move it to a separate thread.